# Reading from hdfs and writting to oracle 12

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> Hi.
>
> I am trying to read from hdfs and write in oracle using pyspark, but I
> have an error. I attach the code that I am using and the error that I
> get:

```
pyspark --driver-class-path "/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar"
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://bigdatalite.localdomain:8020/user/oracle/ACTIVITY/part-m-00000")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
people = parts.map(lambda p: Row(name=p[0], age=p[1]))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521/orcl"
properties = {
    "user": "MOVIEDEMO",
    "password": "welcome1",
    "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
}
schemaPeople.write.jdbc(url=url, table="ACTIVITY", mode="append", properties=properties)
```

..and the error that show is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 530, in jdbc
    self._jwrite.mode(mode).jdbc(url, table, jprop)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:453)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

PD: I using spark 1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Url should be specified in the "service" format, ie.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl
```